# Wordpress can't install plugin, solve with chown but can't FTP

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, centos

I have VPS server with centos 7 and my directory is /home/admin/public_html and i put some websites (wordpress) on it. My problem is when i tried to update or install wordpress plugin, it didn't work because of permission. So i find this solution on google :

chown -R apache:apache /home/admin/public_html

Problem solved. I can update plugin or install new wordpress plugin. But i face new problem now : i can't upload file using FTP software with the error message : 553 can't open that file. Permission denied. To solve this i revert back with : chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/public_html but i can't install/update plugin on my wordpress dashboard again.

How to make right permission so that i can installed plugin and also upload using FTP software?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the error showing when you are try to install plugin using wordpress dashboard? Is it asking ftp details?

Comment: yes asking for my FTP account.

Comment: Then can you please paste this to your wp-config file? 

define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

Comment: i did before. But did't work. The only work way is chown -R apache:apache /home/admin/public_html but cause error when uploading file via FTP .

Answer (score 0):

By default the configuration of the owner is `www-data` in the Ubuntu configuration of Apache2 (don't know what is the default for Centos): this means Wordpress tries to access the folder where it is installed as `www-data` but can't as this folder is registered to some other user/group.

The solution: either you change the ownership of the wordpress folder to the apache user or add the current owner to the apache group.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/WordPress/Installation
```